# Would it be possible to have a script obtain Apple ID details of an iPhone via a Mac or pc?

Tags: applescript, apple-id, password

I use a previously used iPhone with an Apple ID signed in, I’m no longer able to contact the owner.

I wish to know if it’s possible to extract the Apple ID of an iPhone via command scripts on a Mac or pc (via a usb cable)!

I had no progress going around this problem , the scripts I saw around were for extracting Apple ID signed in “on a Mac”.

Comment: What do you mean with "extract the Apple ID of an iPhone"? Do you want to know the Apple ID the phone is locked to? Which version of iOS are you running?

Comment: If you have the passcode, the AppleID it's registered to will be the first thing in Settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you figure this out, be sure to claim a bug bounty from Apple.

Partial user data extraction from an iPhone could be worth up to $100,000

- https://developer.apple.com/security-bounty/payouts/

The phone is designed to not divulge personal information like an email. If you only got the AppleID, that might be a much smaller payout than the max amount.

In your case, you should probably erase the device and if you determine it’s activation locked, contact Apple if the owner didn’t show the information on the Lock Screen.